# Advance search function of google search using javascript but getting some problems

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the code of the form using which I'm trying to fetch the value for the query string.

```html
<form id="form1">
                <label for="allthesewords"> all these words</label>
                <input type="text" id="allthesewords">
                <br>
                <label for="thisexactwordphrase">this exact word phrase</label>
                <input type="text" id="thisexactwordphrase">
                <br>
                <label for="anyofthese">any of these</label>
                <input type="text" id="anyofthese">
                <br>
                <label for="noneofthese">none of these</label>
                <input type="text" id="noneofthese">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Advance Search" onClick="advanceSearch()">
            </form>
```

This one is the javascript function where I'm building my query string.

```js
        function advanceSearch(){
            document.getElementById("form1").action="https://www.google.com/search?as_q="+document.getElementById("allthesewords").value+"&as_epq="+document.getElementById("thisexactwordphrase").value+"&as_oq="+document.getElementById("anyofthese").value+"&as_eq="+document.getElementById("noneofthese").value;
            return true;
        }
```

So, the actual problem is while clicking on the submit button it must redirect to this url
https://www.google.com/search?as_q=Harvard%20univeristy%20students&as_epq=students%20of%20Harvard%20Univeristy&as_oq=Harvard&as_eq=almamater
However, when I run my code it just redirects to this url:
https://www.google.com/webhp.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">
                    <p>Find page with</p>
                    <input class="input_bar" type="text" name="as_q" placeholder="all these words">
                    <input class="input_bar" type="text" name="as_epq" placeholder="this exact word or phrase">
                    <input class="input_bar" type="text" name="as_oq" placeholder="any of these words">
                    <input class="input_bar" type="text" name="as_eq" placeholder="none of these words">
                    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Advance Search">
                </form>
```

Use it!